# how to move a file from one folder to another error

Tags: r

I am using Mac and I have a file in the root which I want to bring it to desktop. 
I have read all the previous command but I could not figure out how to do it.

```
origindir<- ("/Users/admin/Library/R/3.2/library/myfile")
targetdir <- ("~/Desktop/")

file.copy(from=origindir, to=targetdir, 
          overwrite = recursive,copy.mode = TRUE)
```

No matter what I do with recursive, I get this error

> Error in file.copy(from = origindir, to = targetdir, overwrite =
>   recursive,  :    object 'recursive' not found

If I remove all and I only do this

```
file.copy(from=origindir, to=targetdir)
```

I get FALSE and no copy was done

Can someone comment on this ?

Comment: Reading the help text, I guess it should be `file.copy( from = origindir, to = targetdir, overwrite = TRUE,  recursive = TRUE, copy.mode = TRUE)`

Comment: @vaettchen I read the help text too, but how could you understand this ???? this is working now

Comment: `overwrite: logical ...` is the hint

Comment: @vaettchen Thanks !

Comment: To move a file (like mv in *nix systems) you can use `file.rename(from=origindir, to="~/Desktop/newName")`. This will remove the original file and put it on the desktop with the new or old name.

Comment: @lmo thanks I think the first option is a better one because as you said it removes the original , but thanks